# Can't get Gridlayout top and bottom margins to be displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I try to display gridlayouts (as rows) in a linearlayout (table)

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
        <!--
        <include layout="@layout/row"></include>
        <include layout="@layout/sep"></include>
        <include layout="@layout/row"></include> 
        -->
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/row"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" <-- problem -->
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"    <-- problem -->
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:columnCount="2"
     android:rowCount="2"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="@color/orange">
    ...
 </GridLayout>
```

sep.xml

```
<View 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#000"
/>
```

In the emulator and in my phone: When I add a row, a sep(arator), a row etc. I have 2 problems:

- the separator rows are not displayed (even if I increase the layout_height)
- the top and bottom margins of the rows (gridlayout) are not taken into account.

I only get a full block of rows with `@color/orange` background color.

**Note 1:** it's displayed correctly in the preview when I uncomment the "include layout" blocks.

**Note 2:** I have to use the GridLayout because I need to merge rows and columns.

I'm running out of ideas.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Edit your question add an image of how it looks...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally it was because `android:layout_marginTop` and `android:layout_marginBottom` tags are handled only from API 26 and my **targetSdkVersion** is 24 in the gradle file.

The layout editor doesn't display any warning. I have to hover the properties to see it.

So to bypass this limitation I did it programmatically using something like this:

```
LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams) row.getLayoutParams();
lp.bottomMargin = lp.topMargin = Utils.getIntFromDP(10, getResources());
row.setLayoutParams(lp);
```